# How to delete window object for testing purpose?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
function isWindowAvailable() {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined';
}
```

**jest test**

```
it('should return false if window is not available', () => {
    const windowClone = Object.assign({}, window);
    // @ts-ignore
    window = undefined;
    expect(isWindowAvailable()).toBe(false);
    window = windowClone;
});
```

I want to test the function `isWindowAvailable()` using `jest` by deleting or somehow mocking `window` object to `undefined`. deleting `delete window` did not work. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **window object** only exists on the browser. 
What you can do, is to use a helper class and mock the window property as follow:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Window test', () => {


    class WindowHelper {
        get window() {
            return !window ? undefined : window;
        }
    }

    it('verify window does not exists', () => {
        let windowHelper = new WindowHelper;
        sinon.stub(windowHelper, "window").value(undefined)

        function isWindowAvailable(helper) {
            return helper.window !== undefined;
        }

        expect(isWindowAvailable(windowHelper)).to.be.false;
        expect(windowHelper.window).to.be.undefined;
    });
});
```

In case you want to use the `isWindowAvailable` function, you will need to pass the helper. It would be better if you only use the **helper class** every time you want work with the `window` object, this way you will get **window** when you are in the browser and **undefined** in other cases. 
Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry. this is browser based. not node.js. I updated my question. I am looking for a way to delete or mock window. In your solution, you changed the source code and passed helper to the function. I don't want to change the src function.

Comment: But `Jest` runs on Node, so it will not work. For browser only testing you can try with `puppeteer` this way your test will be able to find the window object.

Comment: I am developing in the node environment. ultimately I will build code to run in the browser.